# Power Automate: My cloud flow runs to completion and reports success..but in reality every step failed

Tags: power-automate

(Flow details at the bottom of the message)

When I run my cloud flow:

```
Run history shows success
I receive 2 emails indicating the success
No page is created in OneNote
Every trigger and action that runs displays this error in the run history:  "Unexpected error. NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource."
```

My Outlook connection indicates: "Permissions."  I deleted and re-created the connection with no change in the results. But the fact that the flow runs indicates that the connection is working.

Cloud flow outline:

```
Trigger when an Office 365 outlook upcoming event is starting soon
Get event information
    if failure
        send failure email
        end
    if Success
        Send success email
        Create OneNote Page
            if Failure
                send failure email
                end
            if Success
                Send success email
                end
```

It looks like the Office 365 connector has an issue.  I deleted it an re-created it.

Flow history image with errors

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I spoke with Microsoft tech support and this is a known issue with firefox and chrome.  When I switched to Edge, the problem went away.